# How to I set a prototype object when a JSON object returns (and that object is out of scope)?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
 //the constructor function
    function NewsScroller() {

    }


    //now put some config objects using the JSON structure
    NewsScroller.prototype.config = {
        serviceUrl : '/NewsProvider.svc/rest/GetNews/',
        pageIndex : 0,
        pageNumbers: 0
    }

//allows the sending of a page
NewsScroller.prototype.getNews = function (pageIndex) {

    //get all the newsItems
    var urlToGetJson = this.config.serviceUrl + pageIndex;


    $.getJSON(urlToGetJson, function (data) {


    alert(this.config.pageNumbers);


        $.each(data.NewsItems, function (i, item) {

            var item1DateSelector = '.scroller-pane #division-' + i + ' .date';
            $(item1DateSelector).html(formattedDate);

        });

    });


}
```

Which throws the error:

> this.config is undefined [Break On
>   This Error]
>   alert(this.config.pageNumbers);

I can see from looking at the code I cannot access the prototype so I have 2 questions:

1) Why cant I access why is it out of scope? Surely a function in a function has access to the memebers contained within that function?
2) If I cant access it how do I set the object 'pageNumbers' in the 'config' object notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's out of scope because `this` loses context, since it's jQuery's ajax callback that is executing the function. Indeed other variables retain their lexical scope, so you can solve this with the `self=this` pattern, or try binding the function:

```
NewsScroller.prototype.getNews = function (pageIndex) {

    //get all the newsItems
    var urlToGetJson = this.config.serviceUrl + pageIndex;
    function ajaxCallback(data) {
        alert(this.config.pageNumbers);
        $.each(data.NewsItems, function (i, item) {
            var item1DateSelector = '.scroller-pane #division-' + i + ' .date';
            $(item1DateSelector).html(formattedDate);
        });
    }

    $.getJSON(urlToGetJson, $.proxy(ajaxCallback, this));

}
```

Using the `self=this` pattern:

```
NewsScroller.prototype.getNews = function (pageIndex) {

    //get all the newsItems
    var urlToGetJson = this.config.serviceUrl + pageIndex,
        self = this;

    $.getJSON(urlToGetJson, function(data) {
        alert(self.config.pageNumbers); // instead of this, we reference self
        $.each(data.NewsItems, function (i, item) {
            var item1DateSelector = '.scroller-pane #division-' + i + ' .date';
            $(item1DateSelector).html(formattedDate);
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: This is great I didn't know about the self=this design pattern! Thanks.